# Save highest file extension to a variable

Tags: bash

I've got files where the extension is a number:

```
backup.1
backup.2
backup.3
```

I now need to check what the highest number is and save this number into a variable. (In the case above it would be i=3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems is actually fairly simple in bash. Bash provides a *parameter expansion with substring removal* that makes it easy to obtain the final number from the filename. It has the form `${var##*.}` which simply searches from the left of the string to the last occurrence of `'.'` removing all character up to, and including the dot, e.g.

```
var=backup.1
echo ${var##*.}
1
```

So all you need to is loop over all files matching `backup.[0-9]*` and keep a `max` variable holding the highest number seen, e.g.

```
max=0
for i in backup.[0-9]*; do 
    [ "${i##*.}" -gt $max ] && max="${i##*.}"
done
echo "max: $max"
```

Output based on your files,

```
max: 3
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Why not `((max = n > max ? n : max))` with `n=${i##*.}`?

Comment: No reason in particular other than the ternary usually makes new scripters eyes roll back in their heads. That would work just fine though.

Answer (score 2):

`highest=$(ls backup* | sort -t"." -k2 -n | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\.(.*)/\1/')`

My files:

```
backup.1
backup.2
backup.3
backup.4
backup.5
backup.6
backup.7
backup.8
backup.9
backup.10
```

Output:

```
echo "${highest}"
10
```

Comment: IMHO there is no need to depend on sort, tail, sed.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann David's solution is also good. Mine could be executed just in the shell command-line, if you need.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do it using `find`? Such us `find ./ -type f -name 'back.*[[:digit:]]' -print | sort -t"." -k2 -n | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\.(.*)/\1/'`